# DrawerLayout.openDrawer sometimes not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I have a *DrawerLayout* that usually works perfectly. I am using a button that opens the drawer by calling this method:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
```

As I said, everything works fine but sometimes when the activity comes back from background the openDrawer method does nothing.

By using

```
mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
```

before and after calling the *openDrawer* method, I can see it is always closed.

I have spent several hours on this. What is going on? Any clue is appreciated!

Comment: Are you overriden your onresume in that activity with causing anything for the drawer layout?

Comment: Nope, I am not overriding any onResume.

Answer (score 2):

Open and close the drawer using it's gravity like this

```
if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    } else {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                    }
```

or use View.VISIBLE and View.GONE in place of Gravity.

Comment: Thanks, but Gravity.START is not working. And View.VISIBLE or View.GONE throws an exception IlegalArgumentException "container is not a sliding drawer".

Comment: in your darwer layout xml file the layout you are including must have gravity set to start.

Comment: Yes, the layout has gravity="start". That is why it usually works.

Comment: then the Gravity thing should work, just add your drawer code here so that  i can have a look at that.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of Gravity. I have tried everything in that aspect. It seems that the problem arises when two instances of the activity are launched; then one of them does not open the drawer. It seems that setting the singleTask flag in the activity solves the problem, though I will do more testing...